# How make blogger with full wide screen for a specific page

Tags: xml, blogger

What I want is that Just like a normal blog there's some space generally for ads, etc on the right side of the blog. 
I have the same thing right now for my blog. But I wanted to make ad page for my where I can show why to advertise with us. So, I want to show do I How to make a specific page's full wide screen on blogger. Please See snapshots to get an idea.
2. How it looks
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-mFcvhLCU2CQ/WQlXlUAsCFI/AAAAAAAAAjg/WP-xrMOXq7oXDYCTb5TMvcHE5mAmtBCgACLcB/s320/image%2B%25281%2529.png
3 How it SHOULD look
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-0qVuQNceFBI/WQlXlrZZ5jI/AAAAAAAAAjk/2QwcacSPAEQIpt5DwlFboFGYUpQ7pRwLwCLcB/s320/image%2B%25282%2529.png
NOTE: I use a custom template. 
Edited

Comment: What have you tried? What's the code you got so far?

Comment: Sir, Please Please help. You can just change my life. I bought this template.

Comment: There is not enough info. You didn't provide relevant code. You should really read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Go to your template> edit HTML and add a new class. lets say:

```
.fullscr
{
with:100%;
}
```

then go to the section you want to be full screen and put it inside that div:

```
<div class="fullscr">
<!--THE CONTENT YOU WANT FULL SCREEN-->
</div>
```

this would normally get the job done, but since you are working with a template only god knows what css styles are defined within it, try this first and if it doesnt work paste the code of your template to see whats the issue. Regards.